# How to backup filesystem with tar using a bash script?

Tags: bash, backup

I want to backup my ubuntu filesystem, and I wrote this little script. It is very basic, but being my first try I am afraid to do mistakes. And since it will take few hours to complete to see results, I think it is better to ask you as experienced programmers if I did something wrong.

I'm particularly interested in `>` will that record output of `mv` or will it output also results of `tar`?
Also variables inside tar command is it correct way?

```
#!/bin/bash

mybackupname="backup-fullsys-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz"

{ time tar -cfpzv $mybackupname --exclude=/$mybackupname --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev / && ls -gh $mybackupname && mv -v $mybackupname backups/filesystem/ ; } > backup-system.log

exit
```

Anything I should know before I run this?

Comment: Another hot tip might be to make a git repository, and then only commit changes (and see what programs etc change in your fs). Next time you want to do a backup, it will only commit the changes you've done and you prevent ending up with many duplicated files that hasn't been changed. Just a tip!

Comment: I have svn running on my home server. this is a fantastic idea!

Comment: I would recommend using git instead of svn though, but that might just be based on my personal opinion. However I find git to be faster and easier to handle in these situations :)

Comment: Please don't edit the original text of your question in a way that changes it's meaning. It makes answers not make sense. You can edit your question and append new things that you've tried.

Comment: Also, consider using [rsync](http://everythinglinux.org/rsync/).  You can even use it for [incremental backup](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sandro, you might want to consider spacing things out in your script and producing individual errors.  Makes things much easier to read.

```
#!/bin/bash

mybackupname="backup-fullsys-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz"

# Record start time by epoch second
start=$(date '+%s')

# List of excludes in a bash array, for easier reading.
excludes=(--exclude=/$mybackupname)
excludes+=(--exclude=/proc)
excludes+=(--exclude=/lost+found)
excludes+=(--exclude=/sys)
excludes+=(--exclude=/mnt)
excludes+=(--exclude=/media)
excludes+=(--exclude=/dev)

if ! tar -czf "$mybackupname" "${excludes[@]}" /; then
  status="tar failed"
elif ! mv "$mybackupname" backups/filesystem/ ; then
  status="mv failed"
else
  status="success: size=$(stat -c%s backups/filesystem/$mybackupname) duration=$((`date '+%s'` - $start))"
fi

# Log to system log; handle this using syslog(8).
logger -t backup "$status"
```

If you wanted to keep debug information (like the stderr of `tar` or `mv`), that could be handled with redirection to a tmpfile or debug file.  But if the command is being run via cron and has output, cron should send it to you via email.  A silent cron job is a successful cron job.

The series of `if`s causes each program to be run as long as the previous one was successful.  It's like chaining your commands with `&&`, but lets you run other code in case of failure.

Note that I've changed the order of options for `tar`, because the thing that comes after `-f` is the file you're saving things to.  Also, the `-p` option is only useful when *extracting* files from a tar.  Permissions are always saved when you create (`-c`) a tar.

Others might wish to note that this usage of the `stat` command works in GNU/Linux, but not other unices like FreeBSD or Mac OSX.  In BSD, you'd use `stat -f%z $mybackupname`.

Answer (score 3):

The file redirection as you have it will only record the output of `mv`.

You can do

```
{ tar ... && mv ... ; } > logfile 2>&1
```

to capture the output of both, plus any errors that may occur.

It's a good idea to always be in the habit of quoting variables when they are expanded.

There's no need for the `exit`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. can you please explain 2>&1 this part? what if I have lets say two && how would that change it? 3>&1 ? What do you mean with quoting variables?

Comment: I also updatede OP can you take a look again please? I added time, so I know how long it took, and also ls to see filesize.

Comment: 1 refers to `stdout` and 2 refers to `stderr`, as in "standard messages" and "error messages". So with `2>&1` you redirect messages for `stderr` to `stdout`. The `&` in front of `1` is a way of saying the `1` is a "file descriptor(can't recall if its the correct term)", otherwise you would have gotten the output from stderr written to a file named `1`. Please note, the order in which you put it is important: E.g `1>file 2>&1` will point both stdout and stderr to file, while `2>&1 1>file` will first set stderr to what stdout points to (your screen most likely) and then redirect stdout to file.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: As Jite described, the numbers refer to the file descriptors. You can chain as many `&&` as you want. It doesn't affect the file descriptors. You will need to redirect `stderr` as I have shown to capture the output of `time`.