# Tar backup error

Tags: linux, backup, tar, linux-mint

I followed this question:
[How to backup filesystem with tar using a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467698/how-to-backup-filesystem-with-tar-using-a-bash-script)

But when I run the script it gives following error:

```
: not found/backup.sh: 2: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
: not found/backup.sh: 5: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
: not found/backup.sh: 7: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
: not found/backup.sh: 10: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
: not found/backup.sh: 12: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: 
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: 13: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#TODAY=$(date +%F)
#HOST=$(hostname)

mybackupname="backup-fullsys-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz"

# Record start time by epoch second
start=$(date '+%s')

# List of excludes in a bash array, for easier reading.

excludes=(--exclude=/FILES/Media/Programs/Mint/Backup/$mybackupname)
excludes+=(--exclude=/proc)
excludes+=(--exclude=/lost+found)
excludes+=(--exclude=/sys)
excludes+=(--exclude=/mnt)
excludes+=(--exclude=/MEDIA)
excludes+=(--exclude=/BACKUP)
excludes+=(--exclude=/FILES)

if ! tar -czf "$mybackupname" "${excludes[@]}" /; then
  status="tar failed"
elif ! mv "$mybackupname" FILES/Media/Programs/Mint/Backup/ ; then
  status="mv failed"
else
  status="success: size=$(stat -c%s backups/filesystem/$mybackupname) duration=$((`date '+%s'` - $start))"


# Log to system log; handle this using syslog(8).
logger -t backup "$status"
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like your file has carriage returns and that you're running it with `sh file`. See steps 1 and 2 on the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). Also, +1 for including the full script and the complete error messages.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, if i run using bash the error message changes to this: /etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 10: $'\r': command not found
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 12: $'\r': command not found
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 21: $'\r': command not found
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
/etc/init.d/backup.sh: line 24: `elif ! mv "$mybackupname" FILES/Media/Programs/'int/Backup/ ; then

Comment: It still sounds like your file has carriage returns. See step 1 in the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 0):

As "That other guy" commented the solution here was to run the dos2unix convert command on the bash file:

```
sudo dos2unix /etc/init.d/backup.sh
```

and running it using bash command not sh command:

```
sudo bash /etc/init.d/backup.sh
```